# Set Global Properties at both Design-time and Run-time

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I'm developing a Silverlight 5 app containing WCF RIA services. The app will make many web service calls and each call requires that `username` and `password` elements and a `dsn` attribute be passed. Some of these calls will use a "system administrator" username and password and some will use the user's own login credentials. In all cases, the `dsn` value will be set at user login.

So my question is, where to store all of these? I'll list my two important scenarios right now and hopefully someone can help.

**Authentication**

I've created a custom Membership Provider that overrides the `ValidateUser(string username, string password)` method to actually do the authentication. The code in that method calls the web service using the username and password provided by the user (in a Child Window that appears when the Main Page is loaded).

On the Child Window, the user can select the DSN they'd like to use; but I have no idea how to get that to the `ValidateUser()` method in my Membership Provider.

**Authorization**

Once I have a user authenticated, I need the server to make a call to get more information about the user and store it as part of their user profile. That way, I can use it later in application logic and UI elements. This call would use the system administrator credentials and the DSN chosen by the user in the Child Window.

The generated proxies do provide `*Completed` events for each SOAP action method. I'm thinking I could assign an event handler and handle this authorization bit there. So, where can I store the system admin credentials that I can access them in my Client and Server projects?

I've implemented my Authentication Domain Service as follows:

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ApplicationServices;

namespace THINKImportSystem.Web
{
  [EnableClientAccess]
  public class AuthenticationDomainService : AuthenticationBase<User>
  {
  }

  public class User : UserBase
  {
  }
}
```